# AngularJS: Custom font icons

Tags: css, angularjs, font-face, font-awesome, glyphicons

As fonts are better than images to show icons in different devices, I want to make **my custom font icon library** like "[Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)", in my AngularJS project.

- *Are there any way to do that?*

I created a font in **.ttf** and **.svg** with my icons, and the result is fine, but any icon have a related letter. For example, the home icon is the letter "H" in the new font.

This method have a little issue in Firefox. In Firefox, before the icon is changed to home icon, you can see the letter "H".

- *What is the best practice to do that?*
- *Is posible to solve the little issue in Firefox?*

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preload the font. FF is using a fallback typeface until the requested face is available.

Why doesn't it happen with FontAwesome?

```
<i class="fa fa-something"></i>
```

generates text and only one face is specified for the generated text even when it's contained in an element with a style that does specify a fallback list.

I suggest you look at the CSS that accompanies FA.

Comment: Thank you! This works in css:   .icon-home:before {content: "H";}. And in HTML only put <i class="myfont icon-home"></i>

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a tool like [Font Custom](http://fontcustom.com/) to generate your custom icon webfonts starting from your svg icons. FontCustom will generate the css and the font files and there are a lot of [options](https://github.com/FontCustom/fontcustom/blob/master/lib/fontcustom/templates/fontcustom.yml) that you can configure.